# Find any part of string in another string transact sql

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql

I have strings in my database that represents days in the week like this:

```
1234567 (all days of the week)
1230567 (all days but Thursday, EU standard - day 1 is Monday)
0000067 (no day apart from Saturday and Sunday)
```

And I need to write an SQL question that checks for overlaps.
For instance:

```
1234500 and 0000067 are NOT overlapping.
while 1234500 and 0030000 are overlapping (the 3).
and 1234500 and 0000567 IS overlapping (the 5).
```

Each entry has an ID, customer number, and this weekday representation.

I was thinking something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM dbo.Customers c
JOIN dbo.Customers c2 ON c.CustomerNumber = c2.CustomerNumber
    AND c.Days <> c2.Days
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND ...?
```

To get two entries that are the same customer but when I come to the WHERE statement I hit a blank. Finding a substring (for instance 3) in both Days fields is very easy, but when any one of the 7 entries can be overlapping and I have to exclude 0 (not active day) then I get confused.

I need some help.

Comment: There might be multiple overlaps too, I only need to find out if it's overlapping or not, I actually don't need to know how much or which days.

Comment: *sigh* pressed enter too fast: 1234560 and 0234567 could theoretically exist in the database.

Comment: Bad ideas that leap to mind: (1) Change all the non-zero characters to ones, convert from a string of binary digits to an integer, then [`&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql) (bitwise AND) integers to detect overlaps. (2) Fudge the strings from digits to XML and ... . (The binary approach might not be so bad if a persistent computed column was kept with the integer value of the week's bitmap.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it. Matching every days string char by char and ignoring 0s (by replacing with non matching values). Below query will return rows where there was no overlapping days (ignoring 0s) for same customer.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM Customers c
JOIN Customers c2 ON c.CustomerNumber = c2.CustomerNumber
and c.days <> c2.days
where
(
REPLACE (substring (c.[days],1,1),'0','8') <> REPLACE (substring (c2.[days],1,1) ,'0','9')
AND 
REPLACE (substring (c.[days],2,1),'0','8') <> REPLACE (substring (c2.[days],2,1) ,'0','9')
AND
REPLACE (substring (c.[days],3,1),'0','8') <> REPLACE (substring (c2.[days],3,1) ,'0','9')
AND
REPLACE (substring (c.[days],4,1),'0','8') <> REPLACE (substring (c2.[days],4,1) ,'0','9')
AND 
REPLACE (substring (c.[days],5,1),'0','8') <> REPLACE (substring (c2.[days],5,1) ,'0','9')
AND
REPLACE (substring (c.[days],6,1),'0','8') <> REPLACE (substring (c2.[days],6,1) ,'0','9')
AND
REPLACE (substring (c.[days],7,1),'0','8') <> REPLACE (substring (c2.[days],7,1) ,'0','9')
)
```

Comment: I thought of that but when I saw the finished solution I thought to myself "yeash, that's ugly, there must be a better way"...

Comment: @Mr.Glaurung agree, there should be some cleaner way of doing this. May be, I will give it a try tomorrow. It has been a long day.

Comment: Thank you soo much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Using two [common table expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx), one for a tiny tally table, the other to split `Days` with [**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) and `substring()` for each position using the tiny tally table along with the [**`count() over()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) windowed aggregation function to count the occurrences of each `Day` by `CustomerNumber`. The final `select` shows each overlapping `Day`:

```
;with n as (
  select i from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7)) t(i)
)
, expand as (
  select c.CustomerNumber, c.Days, d.Day
    , cnt = count(*) over (partition by c.CustomerNumber, d.Day)
  from Customers c
    cross apply (
      select Day = substring(c.Days,n.i,1)
      from n
      ) d
  where d.Day > 0
)
select * 
from expand
where cnt > 1
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/SZUANG12356

with test setup:

```
create table Customers (customernumber int, days char(7))
insert into Customers values 
 (1,'1234500')
,(1,'0000067') -- NOT overlapping
,(2,'1234500')
,(2,'0030000') -- IS overlapping (the 3).
,(3,'1234500')
,(3,'0000567') -- IS overlapping (the 5).
;
```

returns:

```
+----------------+---------+-----+-----+
| CustomerNumber |  Days   | Day | cnt |
+----------------+---------+-----+-----+
|              2 | 1234500 |   3 |   2 |
|              2 | 0030000 |   3 |   2 |
|              3 | 1234500 |   5 |   2 |
|              3 | 0000567 |   5 |   2 |
+----------------+---------+-----+-----+
```

---

Reference:

- [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)
- [table value constructor `(values (...),(...))`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql)
- [**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [**`over()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)
- [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)

Comment: Thank you soo much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Without any DDL (underlying table structure) it's impossible to understand where the data lives that you'll be comparing. That said, what you are trying to do will be simple using [ngrams8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/).

Note this query:

```
declare @searchstring char(7) = '1234500';
select * from dbo.ngrams8k(@searchstring,1);
```

**returns**

```
position    token 
----------- ------
1           1     
2           2     
3           3     
4           4     
5           5     
6           0     
7           0
```

with that in mind, this will help you:

```
-- sample data
declare @days table (daystring char(7));
insert @days values ('0000067'),('0030000'),('0000567');

declare @searchstring char(7) = '1234500';

-- how to break down and compare the strings
select 
  searchstring    = @searchstring, 
  overlapstring   = OverlapCheck.daystring,
  overlapPosition = OverlapCheck.position,
    overlapValue    = OverlapCheck.token
from dbo.ngrams8k(@searchstring, 1) search
join 
(
  select * 
  from @days d
  cross apply dbo.ngrams8k(d.daystring,1)
  where token <> 0
) OverlapCheck on  search.position = OverlapCheck.position 
                  and search.token = OverlapCheck.token;
```

Returns:

```
searchstring overlapstring overlapPosition      overlapValue
------------ ------------- -------------------- ---------------
1234500      0030000       3                    3
1234500      0000567       5                    5
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!